# navbar fixed button on collapse show

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to keep the position of the dark mode toggler on show of collapse. I'm using bootstrap but am fine with custom css. I've tried moving the toggler outside of the collapse and above the title but it's still moving. Is there a bootstrap class I'm overlooking?

[header collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkP2c.png)

[header not collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3IoO.png)

[header potential fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6i7e.png) **new

Navbar.jsx

```
<nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light custom-nav'>
        <button className='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarNav' aria-controls='navbarNav' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation'>
            <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
        </button>
        <NavLink className='navbar-brand' to={props.url[0]}>{props.title}</NavLink>
        <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarNav'>
            <ul className='navbar-nav'>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                    <NavLink className='nav-link nav-link-ltr' activeclassname='active' to={props.url[1]}>{props.link[1]}</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                    <NavLink className='nav-link nav-link-ltr' activeclassname='active' to={props.url[2]}>{props.link[2]}</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                    <NavLink className='nav-link nav-link-ltr' activeclassname='active' to={props.url[3]}>{props.link[3]}</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='checkbox' onChange={toggleDarkMode} />
            <label for='checkbox' class='checkbox-label'>
                <i class='fas fa-sun'></i>
                <i class='fas fa-moon'></i>
                <span class='ball'></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Flip the order of the 2 `<div> ` elements, i suspect that should either do the trick or be the first step towards the fix; but i cannot really try it out with this snippet of code.

Comment: I tried that and it works for my original question but in desktop view, the toggler is moved to the left of the title. See updated image in the question.

Comment: If you need more accurate advice on how to fix it you should post an actual test/run-reproducable sample here. Currently there is only some partial html (its template code by the looks of it), and none of the CSS. If you have a runnable snippet here, which people can run to see the result, that'd be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you use "position:absolute" for the toggler, it'll stay in place when the header is expanded and all the elements around the toggler are shifted.